# How to disable MouseLook when FPC collide to an object?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript, gameobject

I am trying to disable mouselook of my FPC when it collide to an object. Here's the code to my GameObject when FPC is trigger:

```
#pragma strict

var showButtons : GameObject;

function Start () {
   showButtons.SetActive(false);
}

function OnTriggerEnter ()
{
    showButtons.SetActive(true);
}

function OnTriggerExit ()
{
    showButtons.SetActive(false);
}

function Update () {

}
```

Now I have a code written in C#, I have no idea on how to convert this code to UnityScript so that I can easily insert this code to my UnityScript code above. By the way this C# code works good. Please help me to transform this C# code to UnityScript.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class pauseCollision : MonoBehaviour {

    MouseLook playerLook;
    MouseLook camLook;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        playerLook = (MouseLook)GameObject.Find("First Person Controller").GetComponent("MouseLook");
        camLook = (MouseLook)GameObject.Find("Main Camera").GetComponent("MouseLook");

        playerLook.enabled = false;
        camLook.enabled = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control a `c#` script from another script, you should write the other script as a `c#` script. I mean you can't access a `c#` script from `js` but you can access `c#` from another `c#` script. I will suggest that you change the other script (which you wrote on your own) to `c#` ( because it is simpler than mouselook script :) ). Also don't be upset if you don't know how to write `c#` in unity. They are very similar. For example in `js` a code would look like this in unity:

```
var speed : int;
function Update(){
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed *Time.deltaTime);
}
```

if we change it to c# format it would look like this:

```
int speed;
void Update(){
transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed *Time.deltaTime);
}
```

It is that simple. Only `function` becomes `void` and while declaring a variable, in `c#` you type `int`, `float`...etc instead of that variable's name. I hope I helped you enough :)